# Automatically returns to the previous activity screen for no reason

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have an activity called `LoanActivity`. I go to this activity from MapsActivity. However, after a few seconds on the `LoanActivity`, it bounces back to `MapsActivity` without me doing anything. I need to fix it but I am not sure why it is happening.

I am trying to update the database for:

1. Locker object to make it unavailable here (its unique id has been passed here from `MapsActivity`),
2. Add the locker's name and latitude and longitude to the Loan object in the database

I am copying the code below:

```
class LoanActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var locationsText: EditText  //to show locker name
    private lateinit var Results: EditText        //to show locker address
    private lateinit var loanLogoutButton: Button

    private lateinit var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
    var aTool: Tool? =null
    var thelocker: Locker?=null
    var lockerName = "XXX"
    var lockerAddress = "YYY"
    var id: String? = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loan)

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

        locationsText = findViewById(R.id.locationsText)
        Results = findViewById(R.id.Results)
        loanLogoutButton= findViewById(R.id.loanLogoutButton)
        loanLogoutButton.isEnabled

        val intent = getIntent()
        //grab the data passed from MapsActivity
        //id of the loan, use this to find other details of it from the database
        id = intent?.getStringExtra("IDofLI")
        //name of the locker is unique, get other details from the database
        val nameOfLocker = intent.getStringExtra("MARKERTITLE")
        val lockerLT = intent.getDoubleExtra("MARKERLT", 0.0)
        val lockerLG = intent.getDoubleExtra("MARKERLG", 0.0)
        doAsync {
            //Find the locker with id, and make it unavailable
            //We will put this loaned item in it
            val reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Locker")
            val addValueEventListener =
                reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        Log.d("LoanA", "3:onCreate")
                        runOnUiThread {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@LoanActivity,
                                "Failed to reach database: $error!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) {
                          data.children.forEach { child ->
                            val locker = child.getValue(Locker::class.java)

                            if (locker != null && locker.name == nameOfLocker) {

                                //This is how you update the database entry
                                var dr = reference.child(child.key.toString())
                                //Create a brand new locker, same as old one, but set available field to 0
                                thelocker = Locker(
                                    locker.name,
                                    locker.day,
                                    locker.month,
                                    locker.year,
                                    0,
                                    locker.zip,
                                    locker.address,
                                    locker.RenterEmail,
                                    locker.LoanerEmail,
                                    locker.rOrl,  //rent or loan
                                    locker.lat,
                                    locker.longt
                                )
                                lockerAddress = locker.address
                                lockerName = locker.name
                                dr.setValue(thelocker)
                                locationsText.setText(lockerName)
                                Results.setText(lockerAddress)
                            }
                        }

                    }

                })

            //Find the Loan item with id
            //Update it in the database to have the lockerName
            val reference2 = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Tool/Loan")
            val addValueEventListener2 =
                reference2.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                        runOnUiThread {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@LoanActivity,
                                "Failed to reach database: $error!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) {
                         data.children.forEach { child ->
                            val tool = child.getValue(Tool::class.java)

                            if (tool != null && child.key.toString() == id) {
                                Log.d(
                                    "TOOL_FOUND*",
                                    "Item being loaned is updated in DB: id=" + child.key
                                )
                                //This is how you update the database entry
                                var dr = reference2.child(child.key.toString())
                                //create a brand new tool, same as old one, but set lockerName
                                aTool = Tool(
                                    tool.day,
                                    tool.month,
                                    tool.year,
                                    tool.type,
                                    tool.available,
                                    tool.zip,
                                    tool.host,
                                    tool.guest,
                                    tool.rOrl,  //rent or loan
                                    nameOfLocker,
                                    lockerLT,
                                    lockerLG,
                                    tool.price
                                )
                                dr.setValue(aTool)
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d("LoanA", "11")
                    }
                })
            Log.d("LoanA", "12")
        }

        loanLogoutButton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("LoanA", "13")
            //send the id of this restaurant to the next screen for reviews
            val intent2 = Intent(this@LoanActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent2)
        }
    }
}
```

No exceptions in the logcat:
I have this:
2020-02-11 22:35:30.211 10084-10127/android.bignerdranch.project1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0a85600: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe0a833d0)
2020-02-11 22:35:30.221 10084-10542/android.bignerdranch.project1 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xc436c980: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
2020-02-11 22:35:31.055 10084-10542/android.bignerdranch.project1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xc436c980: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xc5fa8210)
2020-02-11 22:35:31.086 10084-10084/android.bignerdranch.project1 I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-02-11 22:35:31.097 10084-10127/android.bignerdranch.project1 I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=948ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=31654948913988, Vsync=31655882247284, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=31655888412820, AnimationStart=31655888480620, PerformTraversalsStart=31655888514520, DrawStart=31655888758120, SyncQueued=31655888793620, SyncStart=31655890131720, IssueDrawCommandsStart=31655890241220, SwapBuffers=31655893764920, FrameCompleted=31655899112020, DequeueBufferDuration=817000, QueueBufferDuration=1703000, 
2020-02-11 22:35:36.905 10084-10084/android.bignerdranch.project1 E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-02-11 22:35:36.917 10084-10127/android.bignerdranch.project1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0a85600: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe0a833d0)
2020-02-11 22:36:00.230 10084-10542/android.bignerdranch.project1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xc436c980: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xc5fa8210)
2020-02-11 22:36:01.110 10084-10084/android.bignerdranch.project1 E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2020-02-11 22:36:01.157 10084-10127/android.bignerdranch.project1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0a85600: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe0a833d0)

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in Logcat? On some devices the app does not close in case of a crash, it gets restarted.

Comment: No exceptions in logcat:

Answer (score 0):

It seems your app is crashing after sometime on `LoanActivity` thats why it came back to `MapsActivity`. Please see your logs when it come back to `MapsActivity`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have added the logcat, there is no exceptions. How do I break out this loop? override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) {
                         data.children.forEach { child ->
                            val tool = child.getValue(Tool::class.java)

Answer (score 0):

No exceptions in the logcat: I have this: 2020-02-11 22:35:30.211 10084-10127/android.bignerdranch.project1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0a85600: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe0a833d0) 2020-02-11 22:35:30.221 10084-10542/android.bignerdranch.project1 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xc436c980: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1 2020-02-11 22:35:31.055 10084-10542/android.bignerdranch.project1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xc436c980: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xc5fa8210) 2020-02-11 22:35:31.086 10084-10084/android.bignerdranch.project1 I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 2020-02-11 22:35:31.097 10084-10127/android.bignerdranch.project1 I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey!

Logcat showing that you are doing some heavy task on UI thread that's why application has  crashed.